# Valgrind does not detect leak in global pointer

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am running `valgrind --leak-check=full test.cpp` on the following code

```
#include <iostream>

int* p = new int[42]; // no leak reported

int main() 
{
    p[0] = 42; // use it
    std::cout << p[0];
}
```

and there is no leak reported:

```
==37293== LEAK SUMMARY:
==37293==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==37293==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==37293==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Whenever I move the definition `int* p = new int[42];` inside `main()`, so it has automatic storage duration, valgrind detects the memory leak. Why doesn't it detect the leak for static storage duration objects? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm curious whether you've seen valgrind report *any* such memory leak prior to the commencement of `main()`, not just this example ? I've no idea when it starts monitoring, but `main()` would seem a reasonable place to sink the hooks in.

Comment: @WhozCraig actually I just start using valgrind (OS X, used Instruments before since there was no version for Yosemite), and was just playing with it.

Comment: So jealous. I still don't have mine up and running on Yosemite. I don't suppose you wrote a blog on setting it up =P ? (wishful thinking, I know).

Comment: @WhozCraig just use [macports](https://www.macports.org/) and install the valgrind-devel via `sudo port install valgrind-devel` ;) Simple. The non-devel is still non-compatible, but the devel version works.

Comment: Heh. *thank you*. Between MacPorts, xcode-select, and valgrind-devel (thus automake, libtool, etc..) my av-autoscan just got a helluva workout. But its installed and looks good. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're still reachable and so are not considered leaked. If you want to show even reachable blocks, pass `--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all` to valgrind.

Generally, this kind of "leak" is not a bug. In your example code, there is no "right place" to put a corresponding `delete`.

Comment: Gonna have to jot that one down. Thanks.